# python script to retrieve names and scale range from an ArcGIS MapServer url

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, layers, json, map-service

i am pretty new at ArcPy.
i need to write a python script to retrieve names and scale range from an ArcGIS Map Service url.
i had a look around json and url2lib but i am lost.

I want to retrieve the layer information (name and scale range) from my ArcGIS Server map service. I am using ArcGIS Server 10.0 SP5.

I try this:

```
import urllib2 
url="http://<myserver-name>/ArcGIS/rest/services/CU/MapServer?f=pjson" 
json = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
```

and i stuck at parsing tha json objetc to get the layer information i am needing.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to provide more details about precisely what you have tried (i.e. a code snippet or two) and where you are stuck, please?  I changed your tag from [tag:mapserver] (an Open Source web map server) to [tag:map-service] because I think you are asking about an ArcGIS for Server map service.

Comment: yes. you are right. i want to retrieve the layer information (name and scale range) from my ArcGIS Server map service. I am using 10.0 SP5. well i try this:import urllib2
url="http://<myserver-name>/ArcGIS/rest/services/CU/MapServer?f=pjson"
json = urllib2.urlopen(url).read() and i stuck at parsing tha json objetc to get the layer information i am needing.

Comment: There is an edit button beneath your question where you can add this information.  I will attempt to do it for you but I urge you to check what I transfer because it is your question.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like using the `read()` method was returning a string. `json.load` will return you a json object that you can then parse:

```
import urllib2
import json

url = "http://<myserver-name>/ArcGIS/rest/services/CU/MapServer?<layer-index>f=pjson" 
response = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

min_scale = response["minScale"]
max_scale = response["maxScale"]
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. it helps a lot. i am parsing the response object and obtaining layer information as wanted